# jsp please help me please for my project about online

Tags: mysql, jsp

how to add data with auto increment value with other records in mysql using jsp.I want to insert data with auto increment values I want jsp codes.

Comment: You've got to add more details (code). Also, use a title that describes the technical problem. See [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have created a MYSQL database, and you add different values through jsp, the auto increment values will automatically be inserted in the database.  (The field must be auto increment in the database) Provide some code, if this does not answer your question.

Comment: I made a database table of 2 records as id autoincrement and name but after inserting the value from jsp page it has one record that is name to be inserted but it does not insert.

Comment: the problem lies in the connection if it is not inserting the data. It is not going to autoincrement if the data is not being inserted. Post some code so we can find out any mistakes

Comment: I want to add more records in it like name but its takes only id.<%
  try{           
 Connection conn=null;
             
  
  String user_1=request.getParameter("user");
  

       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
conn =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/data","root","");
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT id FROM user");
int id=2;
if(rs.last()){
id=rs.getInt("id")*55555;
}
st.executeUpdate("insert into user(id) values("+id+")");
out.println("Data is inserted successfully");
}
catch(Exception e){}
%>

Comment: edit your question to post the code. cannot make out anything from the comment. Click on edit, insert the code, select the code and click on {} symbol to make convert to code in your question above

Comment: I want to add more records in it like name but its takes only id.{<% try{ Connection conn=null; String user_1=request.getParameter("user"); Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); conn =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/data","root",""); Statement st = conn.createStatement(); ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT id FROM user"); int id=2; if(rs.last()){ id=rs.getInt("id")*55555; } st.executeUpdate("insert into user(id) values("+id+")"); out.println("Data is inserted successfully"); } catch(Exception e){} %>}

Comment: edit the question to add the code brother

Comment: i understand that you are new to SO, no one here can help you without having any code in the question itself

Comment: only tell me can we add both data in database like id is autoincremented and name (char) in jsp page how with one textbox in jsp for name and what about id it is autoincremented.

Comment: You can add just the name field. Since the id is auto incremented, MySql will automatically add it. So just add the name, id will be added on its own. If the answer helps please select the tick mark beside my original answer. Have a great day and let me know if u need any more help

Comment: see I have made a jsp page and inserted only name field.but the database which i have created have tables id and name if i insert name from jsp page it takes error it do not insert.

Comment: Then maybe there is a problem with the connection with the database. Hope you have used write syntax for the connection string

Comment: http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/prepared-statement-query.shtml   

This link can be a good start.

Comment: the last link given to you should solve all the questions, mark my answer as the correct answer by clicking on the check mark on my original answer

Comment: thanks to user1063280 it was solved.

Comment: If it was solved, please mark it as an answer. on the top. there will be a tick mark, click on it and it will turn green. I need the rep brother